# split by newline wildcard backslash

Tags: python

Split by `\n`wildcard`/`. I have the following text:

```
wiring /(cid:3)(cid:9)waərŋ/ noun 1. a network of wires
wisdom tooth /(cid:3)(cid:9)wzdəm tu(cid:11)θ/ noun one of
the four teeth in the back of the jaw
witch  hazel  /(cid:3)(cid:9)wtʃ  (cid:4)hez(ə)l/ noun  a  lotion
made  from  the  bark  of  a  tree
```

I want to split it to get the words that are defined, so I want to split by `\n./`, but when I use

```
  txt.split('\n./')
```

or

```
  txt.split('\\n./')
```

It just returns `txt`

Comment: You realize that this won't match the first word since there is no newline before it. And, the `.` operator only matches one character.

Comment: @jakekimds `.` is not an operator in `str.split()`. It is a simple dot.

Comment: @user5061 It looks like he is trying using regex. However, he must compile it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) is different from [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split). `.` is a simple dot in `str.split()`, not a wildcard.

```
s = "I like dogs"
print(s.split('.'))   # Prints ['I like dogs']
```

---

To extract only the "words" like: `'wiring', 'wisdom tooth', 'witch  hazel'` you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
l = re.findall(r'(.+?)\s*/.*?\n', s)
```

`findall()` returns a list with all matches.

`.` matches any non newline character, `+` matches 1 or more of those. `()` is a capturing group (the part of the match that will be "stored"). `*` means 0 or more of the previous. `\s` is the whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative, although I do think regular expression is the best way to go.

You can first split the `\n`, iterate the list, find `/` and split the `/` to return the first item:

```
txt = '''wiring /(cid:3)(cid:9)waərŋ/ noun 1. a network of wires
wisdom tooth /(cid:3)(cid:9)wzdəm tu(cid:11)θ/ noun one of
the four teeth in the back of the jaw
witch  hazel  /(cid:3)(cid:9)wtʃ  (cid:4)hez(ə)l/ noun  a  lotion
made  from  the  bark  of  a  tree'''

for line in txt.split('\n'):
    if '/' in line:
        print line.split('/')[0].strip()

wiring
wisdom tooth
witch  hazel
```

or list comprehension to do it all at once:

```
print [line.split('/')[0].strip() for line in txt.split('\n') if '/' in line]

['wiring', 'wisdom tooth', 'witch  hazel']
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as posed, the `.split()` operator needs to be performed on the actual variable. When you enter `txt.split(...)`, you are actually splitting the variable `txt`. So, define your text above as a string, then split that string.

```
textarray = 'wiring...'
textarray.split('\n./')
```